# Group by operation with condition as agg function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in this fashion

```
node touch1 touch2 touch3 touch4 touch5
A    Best   Mid    Mid     
A           Best   Worst  Worst
```

I want to have a groupby node based on a condition tree so that I will have in return

```
node touch1 touch2 touch3 touch4 touch5
A    Best   Best   Mid    Worst
```

Or basically if there is Best show Best, if not but there is Mid show Mid and if not but there is Worst show Worst.

I am trying something like

```
group_cols = ["touch1", "touch2", "touch3", "touch4", "touch5"]
output.groupby(group_cols).agg({'Best':lambda val: (val == "Best").any(),'Mid':lambda val: (val == "Mid").any(), 'Worst':lambda val: (val == "Worst").any()}).reset_index()
```

But cant make it work. I think I am missing something. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: The text labels, {Best, Mid, Worst}, are nice enough. But you will be happier if you convert them to integers. Then you can use `<` comparison operators, or `min()` / `max()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a mapping dictionary as suggested is the best approach.

```py
import pandas as pd
mapping_dict = {'Best': 0, 'Mid': 1, 'Worst': 2, None: 3}
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "node": ["A", "A"],
    "touch1": ["Best", None],
    "touch2": ["Mid", "Best"],
    "touch3": ["Mid", "Worst"],
    "touch4": [None, "Worst"],
    "touch5": [None, None],
})
result = df.groupby('node').agg(lambda x: {value: key for key, value in mapping_dict.items()}[min(x.map(mapping_dict))])
print(result)
```

Gives :

```
     touch1 touch2 touch3 touch4 touch5
node                                   
A      Best   Best    Mid  Worst   None
```

Note that `{value: key for key, value in mapping_dict.items()}` is simply the invert (key: value becomes value: key) of mapping_dict and is used to retrieve the original encoding.

Comment: thank you very much guys, both solutions were really good however I am not brave enough yet to upgrade pandas

Answer (score 0):

As J_H says in the comments, text labels by themselves are generally hard to work with. I'd suggest converting them to [categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) first, and then selecting the highest ranked one in your aggregation.

To do this, first build the categories in order of smallest to largest:

```py
categories = ["Worst", "Mid", "Best"]
```

Then, convert all of the columns that aren't `node` to this categorical type:

```py
df = df.set_index("node")
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Categorical(x, categories=categories, ordered=True))
```

Now, if you groupby `node`, the aggregation can just take the largest value in each column:

```py
df.groupby("node").max().reset_index()
```

This gives the desired result:

```
node touch1 touch2 touch3 touch4 touch5
A    Best   Best   Mid    Worst  NaN
```

Note: If you don't want to keep your data as categorical after this, you will need to convert it back with `df = df.astype(str)`.

---

**Data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "node": ["A", "A"],
    "touch1": ["Best", None],
    "touch2": ["Mid", "Best"],
    "touch3": ["Mid", "Worst"],
    "touch4": [None, "Worst"],
    "touch5": [None, None],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `key` option in `sort_values` of pandas 1.1.0+

```
d = {'Best': 0, 'Mid': 1, 'Worst': 2, '': 3}
df_final = df.groupby('node').agg(lambda x: x.sort_values(key=lambda x: x.map(d))
                                             .head(1))

Out[600]:
     touch1 touch2 touch3 touch4 touch5
node
A      Best   Best    Mid  Worst
```